# MAUI default color flashes after splash screen

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

Just like the title says; the default purple color MAUI uses flashes after the splash screen in my app.

This issue only seems to occur on iOS and not Android. Although, I've only tested Android while running the debugger so I don't know how it would look like as a published Android app. On iOS I've only been able to test it with testflight, due to [.NET MAUI using the default assets when running it with the debugger](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8685).

This is the relevant code from *.csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#000000" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\bilvision.svg" Color="#FFFFFF" BaseSize="544,544" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: .svg -> .png. Try it.

Comment: FWIW: Maui automatically converts all .svgs into .pngs, during build. Also, since the default Maui color happens AFTER the splash screen, sounds like it is during initialization of the first Maui page. Maybe try a very simple first page, so it displays quickly. Set desired background color.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I'll give it a go, though my current first page is quite simple as it is already. Just 2 input fields with a submit button. Perhaps it's worth mentioning that I'm using MAUI Blazor and not XAML

Comment: Which version of Android are you targeting? Handling of splash screens was replaced at around SDK 31 if I recall. Does MAUI take this into account?

Comment: Android (31+) works just fine, so I guess that MAUI takes that into account. This issue only affects iOS devices though. From what I've tested anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out this, because people are still reporting it as bug:

> Important
> .NET MAUI converts SVG files to PNG files. Therefore, when adding an SVG file to your .NET MAUI app project, it should be referenced from XAML or C# with a .png extension. The only reference to the SVG file should be in your project file.

Especially if you have been developing on Android (for cost and complexity reasons), and used everywhere SVG. You will notice that when testing on IOS you wont see resources. You have to walk through your whole project files and replace it.

Comment: The issue isn't that my resources aren't showing up, they are showing up just fine. The issue is the moment my custom splash screen disappears there's a purple flash right before my first view/page renders.

Comment: Did you replace your .SVG with .PNG? And another question. Is this Release? The performance in Release and Debug differs greatly. Many of the problems I get in debug, I do not get in release.

Comment: Do you have perhaps "loading..." on this screen?

Comment: Yes I have tried replacing the SVG's with PNG's, there is no difference between the two. This happens in both Debug and Release and no, there's no 'Loading...' on the page...

Comment: I've seen the comment you have added about using blazor. This seems to me like loading of your blazor page. It shows after the splash screen and is not related to it.

Comment: I highly doubt that. The purple flash happens before the very first html/razor even renders.

Comment: @Zita - actually, I agree with H.A.H. I don't recall anyone reporting this problem when first page is a normal Maui page, so it sounds like a bug re Maui Blazor - sounds like there is a moment while Maui loads the BlazorWebView, during which it shows its standard background. IMPORTANT: As a test, please make a non-Blazor first page and set its background color. Does the flash still appear? If not, then please report as a Splash Screen + Maui Blazor iOS bug at github maui issues. Include a link to a simple public github repo. Thanks!

Comment: @Zita - Are you testing on an actual device (as opposed to an emulator)?

Comment: I stand corrected! I apologize for my dismissive comment @H.A.H, you were indeed correct. From your @ToolmakerSteve suggestion I looked through the already existing XAML which comes with the empty MAUI Blazor template, and I noticed there were a few `BackgroundColor` attributes which sets the color to the purple color MAUI uses. I modified these values and it pretty much solved the issue. Thanks to both of you guys! :)

Comment: Excellent! To help others who encounter this in future, please add Your Answer below, showing where you found that code, what it was originally, and what you changed it to. Thanks!